# Free-tagging user accounts

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to free tag user accounts in Drupal 6? For example, a user with appropriate permissions would be able to add tags created on the fly to any user account. If I could limit which user roles could be tagged, that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually worked out how to do this: use Content Profile module to extend the user account with a node of a custom type, and then create a free tag for that node type.